# L'absence du genre neutre en français

Tags: grammaire, histoire, genre, latin

Toutes les langues que je parle (avec une maîtrise décroissante: grec, anglais, français, roumain, allemand) hormis le français comportent trois genres : masculin, féminin et neutre. Il se peut d'autres langues ne comportent que deux genres (masculin/féminin) mais je ne suis intéressé qu'au français. En cherchant alors pourquoi le français ne comporte pas le genre neutre j'ai rencontré le lien :

http://projetbabel.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=13400

sur la disparition du neutre en latin. Vu que le français est une langue romane, cela explique-t-il l'absence du neutre en français ou y-a-t-il une période où le français possédait le genre neutre ? Dans ce cas pourquoi cette disparition ?

Existe-t-il des évolutions linguistiques introduisant le neutre en français ? Par exemple,  en suédois, on a récemment introduit le pronom neutre hen.
Quelle est la relation entre le masculin générique et l'absence de neutre ?

Comment: Apprends l'italien, l'espagnol, le portugais, le catalan, l'occitan, le sarde, le corse, le romanche, l'arpitan et autres... Le "mouton noir", c'est le roumain !

Comment: Houla!! C'est que c'est compliqué cette histoire. Et ce d'autant que, si on veut être factuel, il faut mentionner l'arbitraire du signe linguistique bref... appeler au secours rien moins que la sémiotique, remonter à l'indo-européen... Pfff... bref... à moins de 50 pages... je me sens pas quoi!

Comment: Certaines personnes commencent à utiliser le pronom `iel` (contraction de il et elle) pour désigner une personne sans faire de distinction sur son genre, mais ça reste très peu fréquent

Comment: @aCOSwt: sans compter les genres qui changent d'une langue à l'autre: le soleil/la lune <=> die Sonne/der Mond.

Comment: @mouviciel : Absolument! Tu donnes-là un exemple très éloquent du fait que les 50 pages d'étude raisonnée tirant toutes les ficelles pour en conclure que dans de très nombreux cas, la décision est en fait **arbitraire**... eh bhein... re Pfff!  ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Vu que le français est une langue romane, cela explique-t-il l'absence du neutre en français ?

Oui. Que je sache, toutes les langues romanes ont perdu le genre neutre, étant donné qu'elles viennent du latin (le roumain étant la seule exception). Le neutre avait disparu du latin, il est donc naturel qu'il soit absent des langues romanes.

Le [neutre](http://projetbabel.org/roumain/grammaire_3_1_3_1.php) du roumain est en réalité plus une création a posteriori qu'une "réintroduction" du neutre latin. C'est un cas très intéressant mais il sort un peu du cadre de la question.

L'introduction du neutre en français est un peu compliquée. En anglais par exemple, les noms, les adjectifs ne s'accordent pas. Tout est neutre, il suffit d'un pronom neutre et toute la phrase est neutre. En français, une grande partie des adjectifs sont genrés, on ne peut pas juste introduire un pronom neutre et rendre toute la phrase neutre.

Ex:

> "[pronom neutre] est triste." → OK
>
> "[pronom neutre] est heureux." → Genré au masculin

Le masculin se comporte comme un neutre dans certains cas, mais il reste très genré.

Si l'on voulait introduire un genre neutre, il faudrait soit une nouvelle terminaison pour tous les adjectifs, ce qui n'est absolument pas réalisable, soit considérer le masculin comme neutre, ce qui est déjà plus ou moins le cas selon les cas, ce qui mène à des ambiguïtés.

> "On a interrogé des expertes" → Uniquement des femmes.
>
> "On a interrogé des experts" → Uniquement des hommes, ou bien des hommes et des femmes ?

Comment savoir si on parle du neutre ou du masculin ? Comment parler d'experts neutres sans donner l'image d'experts uniquement ou majoritairement masculins ?

Ces problèmes sont liés à la structure même du français (et des langues romanes en général) et rendent très difficile l'utilisation du neutre sans implication ou ambiguïté en français. L'écriture inclusive est une tentative de répondre à ces problèmes mais elle ne fait pas du tout l'unanimité, étant donné la difficulté de rendre neutre une langue fondamentalement très genrée.

Comment: Heu... pour ce qui est du début de ta réponse... j'aurais dit non ! Et si on complète la question par la suite donnée par @dimitris ("y a-t-il eu une période") alors c'est encore plus non! D'une part le neutre n'a jamais disparu du latin. (Du latin-vulgaire peut-être) et d'autre part, **le français ancien avait conservé le neutre** (du latin) dans la déclinaison des adjectifs, pronoms et participes passés. Pas d'accord avec votre réponse donc. Tout n'est pas simplifiable ainsi.

Comment: @aCOSwt Je t'invite à rédiger une réponse avec tes sources :)

Comment: En fait, l'Italian aussi a des vestiges du neutre latin, n'est-ce pas? C'est comme le 'neutre' roumain: *il lenzuolo - le lenzuola; il braccio - le braccia*, et cetera. // Un autre fait/hypothese intéressante: si je me souviens correctement, le suffix *-a* du neutre latin et grec est probablement dérivé d'un suffix qui est la source aussi du *-a* singulier des mots feminins.